# Is it possible to have 2 tabs with multi select list box on a google sheet using an app script?

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to have 2 tabs with multi select list box on a google sheet using an app script?

It would be great to have 2 tabs, each with their own multi select list box, in one side bar using apps script.

I can only get 1 multi select list box, but I want to be able to have 2 tabs

Multi Select Box:

[Multi Select Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAkfg.png)

I want this Multi Select Box in 2 tabs as shown below:

[2 Tabs in Sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukfso.png)

Comment: When you say multiselect list box do you mean a cell that has multiple selections like in validations?

Comment: We need  a bit more information if you wish additional help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

[image]

Every one of the little triangles in upper right of cell is a separate drop down and in this case they would have the same options to chose from but they can be different as well.

Comment: Hey @Cooper, I just added pics on my original post. Thanks!